# Generating different dimension images while uploading image file from custom plugin page

Tags: images, uploads

There is a file upload provision in my custom plugin page.

On this, I'm saving the image details into post table as an `attachment` post type and moving the uploaded file manually. Here is my code:

```
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$filetype = $_FILES['img_name'];
$filename = $filetype['name'];
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_upload_pdf']['tmp_name'],$wp_upload_dir['path'].'/'.$_FILES['test_upload_pdf']['name']);
```

Is there any alternative way for `move_uploaded_file()` in WordPress to get the different dimension of the given image automatically?

Comment: Try adding `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` and  `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` after `wp_insert_attachment()`. See [the first example here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) for details.

Comment: `$absFilename = $wp_upload_dir['path'].'/'.$filename;
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $absFilename);
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );`

Comment: The above code done my job. Thanks again @DaveRomsey.

Comment: Good, glad to hear! Please add that code as an answer, then stop by in a couple of days and click the checkmark next to it to accept it. This helps keep the site tidy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resized different dimension image sets are generated by using wp_generate_attachment_metadata and wp_update_attachment_metadata method.

```
$absFilename = $wp_upload_dir['path'].'/'.$filename;
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $absFilename);
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

This will update the image details in the  wp_postmeta table.

Thanks @DaveRomsey